# Questions clarification needed for showing that $H$ is an abelian group of odd order.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

For the following exercise, I have some question about the notation and hint:

Let $(G, *)$ be a finite group of even order.  Suppose that half of the elements of $G$ are of order 2 and the rest of the elements of $G$ form a subgroup $H$.  Show that $H$ is an abelian subgroup of odd order.

Hint:  the number of elements of order 2 is odd.  Thus $\lvert G \rvert =2n,$ where $n$ is odd. Let $b$ be an element of order 2 and $c\in H.$  Then $bc\notin H$.  Hence, $b*c*b=c^{-1}$ for all $c\in H$.  Deduce that $c^{-1}*d^{-1}=d^{-1}*c^{-1}$ for all $c,d\in H$.

Questions:  what is the difference between the binary operation $*$ versus plain multiplication.  Meaning, difference between $b*c$ compare $bc$.  Also, why is it necessary that $bc\notin H$.  Is it related to $H\cap cH=\emptyset$. also, for $d^{-1}$, do i let it equal to $b*d*b$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There should be no difference between $bc$ and $b\ast c$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you for the reply.  Do I take $d^{-1}=b*d*b$ and also is the reason I cited for why $bc\notin H$ correct?